# Invalid SQL from a has_many :through relation on an STI model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

[Here is a self contained gist demonstrating the problem](https://gist.github.com/naiyt/7a761b44abc28f9157ff). That will pass on Rails >= 3.2.12, but fails on Rails >= 4.0.

I'm working on updating an application from Rails 3.2.12 to Rails 4. We have a base model that's inherited by several others. The child models define a `has_many :through` relation to a third model. This is the basic setup:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :join_child_others
  after_create :set_active_id

  def set_active_id
    other_models.update_all(:active_id => id)
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  has_many :other_models, :through => :join_child_others
end


class OtherModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :join_child_others
end

class JoinChildOther < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  belongs_to :other_model
end
```

In Rails 3 when `other_models.update_all(:active_id => id)` runs, it generates this SQL:

```
UPDATE `other_models`
INNER JOIN `join_child_others` 
ON `other_models`.`id` = `join_child_others`.`other_model_id`
SET `other_models`.`active_id` = 1
WHERE `join_child_others`.`parent_id` = 1
```

In Rails 4, we get:

```
UPDATE `other_models`
INNER JOIN `join_child_others` 
ON `other_models`.`id` = `join_child_others`.`other_model_id`
SET `other_models`.`active_id` = 1
WHERE `join_child_others`.`parent_id` = NULL
```

Notice the `WHERE` clause looking for a null `parent_id`.

It seems like the issue is the inheritance. If I rewrite this to not have the inheritance it works as expected on Rails 4. Also, it's not clear from this simple example, but there are reasons we need the `has_many :other_models` in the child.

The other weird thing is that `test.other_models` works, but `test.other_models.to_sql` seems to generate the incorrect SQL:

```
SELECT "other_models".*
FROM "other_models"
INNER JOIN "join_child_others"
ON "other_models"."id" = "join_child_others"."other_model_id"
WHERE "join_child_others"."parent_id" = NULL
```

As it works fine in Rails 3, I'm thinking this may be a Rails 4 bug. The same thing happens in stable versions of Rails 4.0, 4.1, and 4.2. I've tested it with MySQL and SQLite.

Comment: create a selfcontained gist like it's described [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#create-a-self-contained-gist-for-active-record-and-action-controller-issues) and submit a bug-report if it still holds

Comment: What is you your rails 4 version. I tried you example, It works for me with rails 4.0.0 and rails 4.2.0. So, I think it is the adapter of your database which have a problem. What is your database? It works for me with PostgreSQL and pg 0.17.1

Comment: @CupraR_on_Rails: I've tested it on stable versions of Rails 4.0, 4.1, and 4.2, and encountered the same thing on all of them. I've tested on MySQL and SQLite, so perhaps it's just an issue with those two.

Comment: @phoet: yeah, I'll probably end up submitting a bug report, but I wanted to see if anybody here had any thoughts first